# Merry Christmas Worldbuilding

Tags: discussion

We have had a great year on worldbuilding, and as christmas has arrived, I thought we could all regale our favorite moments this past year.

For me, the best part of this year was the amount of new users we got, the feeling of hearing their ideas and helping with their questions gave me a sense of power I have yet to match.

Comment: Apparently nobody had any favorite moments in 2016. Personally, I don't think the year was *that* bad for Worldbuilding ;-)

Comment: Wow this is actually super sad. I wish I had seen this back in 2016.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite part of 2016 on Worldbuilding (my first year on the site) was doing a deep dive into a subject to make answers. The best were using combinations of physics, math and computer knowledge, and spending several hours building and verifying models to test things. The two best examples are [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/58485/temperatures-in-an-eccentric-orbit/63574#63574) and [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/62948/season-cycle-that-would-occur-on-a-habitable-planet-that-orbits-two-suns/62992#62992).

It is stuff like this that has lead to me poking my nose into this site every day, and coming back to older questions to keep answering them. I've been working on a computer model to answer [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57974/circulation-patterns-on-a-tidally-locked-binary-planet) for months now. These questions are like the best (optional) homework assignments ever. Someday I'll answer them all.

On the other hand, the two answers linked in the first paragraph have 4 upvotes to compare with maybe 8 hours of work. Meanwhile a [tongue-in-cheek two minute answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/60102/the-10000-year-skyscraper/60140#60140) can get me about 30 times the votes. Oh well.